# Dwarf Fortress no Flux Stone

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I settled somewhere with Flux Stone.

I'm on the 12th layer and I still haven't struck Flux Stone.

Is this a bug, or do I need to dig deeper for Flux Stone?

Answer (score 3):

Deeper and possibly wider.

Bear in mind that your location almost always had more than one biome; not all of them may have been described as containing flux stone.

I recommend digging a few exploratory shafts well away from your actual fort, going straight down for a couple dozen Z-levels just to see what layers you punch through.

Comment: Sometimes there is only a little bit of flux stone and it tends to be near the edges.